# Can't ping Ubuntu guest from Windows 10 host via Host Only Adapter

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Problem: Unable to connect/ping Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS(Guest in Virtual Box) from Windows 10 host.

[image]

192.168.56.103 is the ip of Ubuntu. That is the screenshot of Windows trying to connect Ubuntu.

Below are the settings present in both the machines:

Windows 10 (Host)
VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter setting:

[image: 10]

Windows 10 (Host) "ipconfig" output:

[image]

Windows 10 firewall is already disabled:
[image]

Virtual Box settings:
Ubuntu VM:
Network settings:

[image]

Ubuntu's ifconfig:

[image]

```
enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.56.103  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.56.255
        inet6 fe80::b50f:e266:caa:d528  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:c3:4e:1c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4  bytes 1830 (1.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 60  bytes 7194 (7.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Firewall already disabled on Ubuntu (Guest):

[image]

Can you share what I am missing for connecting the Ubuntu guest from Windows 10 host?

I have no issue accessing the internet inside the Ubuntu guest. I have already gone through the following posts but found no success in solving my problem

[Can't Ping Ubuntu Guest from Windows 7 Host](https://superuser.com/questions/864793/cant-ping-ubuntu-guest-from-windows-7-host)

https://serverfault.com/questions/908615/virtualbox-and-windows-10-cant-connect-to-a-server-hosted-on-virtualbox

Comment: I believe its a gateway issue. You should try adding a default gateway to VirtualBox Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please

```
iptables -L -v -n
```

also does

```
ping 192.168.56.103
ping 192.168.56.1
```

on ubuntu go well?

Also please

```
arp -a
```

Comment: On Ubuntu terminal: ping 192.168.56.1 gives me output but 192.168.56.103 gives me timed out, strange! Can you share why Ubunutu itself is unable to ping 192.168.56.103?

Comment: Incoming ICMP packets are somehow blocked.
Maybe all incoming traffic is blocked. Have you checked iptables?

Comment: wait, I rebooted the ubuntu and I can ping  192.168.56.103 and 192.168.56.1  both from Ubuntu but Windows the problem remains the same.